# on press button textfield in javafx

Tags: java, validation, javafx

i have a form for creating new **user**,and i want when i write a **username** which exists in my `database` to show me the image with the `X` or the **image** with a **cross**.But it doesn't show me like i want,if i write **username** **someusername** and the **someusername** exists in my `database` it need to set the **image** to be the `X_image` otherwise the `cross_image` ,i write some code..

```
@FXML
private void onChangeUserField() {
    if( (usernameField.getText() == null || usernameField.getText().length() == 0)
            || UserController.existUser(usernameField.getText())){
        usernameVerifyField.setImage(Config.thex_image);
    } else {
        usernameVerifyField.setImage(Config.cross_image);
    }
}
```

and for this code if i have a user with "**someusername**" username in `database` , when i write "**someusername**" in the `textfield` it show me the `x_image` ,and if i add just one "e" like "**someusernamee**" it show me the `cross_image` ..

**Question** :- why it show me like that?

Comment: How did you implement the UserController.existUser method?

Comment: <!-- language: lang-java -->
public static boolean existUser(String username) {
        boolean temp = false;
        for(User u : USERS) {
            if(u.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                temp = true;
                break;
            } else {
                temp = false;
                //break;
            }      
        }
        return temp;
    }

Comment: please edit the question. What image do you want to show if the input is correct? X and cross is the same to me (at least linguistic-wise).

Comment: The condition seem invalid, shouldn't it be "usernameField.getText() == null || usernameField.getText().length() == 0)
            || ! UserController.existUser(usernameField.getText()" with ! before exist...

Comment: I tried but and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

the question is unclear... if it has the data, it should populate the **X Image** not the **Cross Image** right?

If so, that is the correct output of yours already i thought?

Comment: yes,but if i have the data it populate with the cross image,and should populate with the x image

Comment: Ok.. i think you should edit your question because it sounds contradicting.

Comment: Anyway, I think logic wise it should be correct. Have a check at the .existUser function. The problem possibly lies there :)

Comment: the method .existUser just return a true(if the user exist) or false(if the user doesn't exist),and this method work good in the other parts of my program,i think my problem is in the condition above

Comment: ... to show me the image with the **X or the image with a cross**... 
...need to set the image to be the **X_image otherwise the cross_image**....

bro... ur question is still contradicting... lol... meh..

Comment: if **(**
 (usernameField.getText() == null || usernameField.getText().length() == 0)
         **||** UserController.existUser(usernameField.getText())
**)** 

ur **someoneusername** exists in the database... and it hits a **true** value in the condition, that's why it show u the **thex_image** ... does this answer your question?